# Can't antialias font

Tags: python, qt, fonts, pyqt, antialiasing

This is the code I wrote, but it seems to apply the antialiasing

```
font = QtGui.QFont("Trajan Pro", 20)
font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
font.setBold(True)
self.setFont(font)
self.shadow = QtGui.QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
self.shadow.setOffset(2,1)
self.shadow.setBlurRadius(2.0)
self.label.setGraphicsEffect(self.shadow)
```

[image: Here's the result]

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
Here's a MCVE

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
class FontWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(FontWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        label = QtGui.QLabel('Hello, this is a test')
        layout.addWidget(label)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        fontDB = QtGui.QFontDatabase()
        fontDB.addApplicationFont(":/TrajanPro-Regular.otf")
        font = QtGui.QFont("Trajan Pro", 20)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.setFont(font)

        shadow = QtGui.QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
        shadow.setOffset(2,1)
        shadow.setBlurRadius(2.0)
        label.setGraphicsEffect(shadow)

        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Foreground, QtCore.Qt.white)
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Background, QtCore.Qt.red)
        self.setPalette(palette)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    window = FontWidget(None)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: New screenshot]

As you can see in S and O, antialias seems to be not properly applied

EDIT 2:

Added the import

Here's a link to download the font:

http://www.fontpalace.com/font-details/TrajanPro-Regular+OTF/

Comment: I would love to help and have dealt with some of these issues, but a code-fragment leaves a lot of work to the folks trying to help.  Please consider providing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok I'm going to do it

Comment: ok, MCVE added as you said

Comment: It *is* antialiasing the font, it's just doing a rough job of it. Maybe their rendering engine has a problem with very thin lines.

Comment: Well, so how I can improve this result?

Comment: @user3489057. That is not an MCVE, because it is using a resource that you have not included. Have you tried with any other fonts? And what platform are you testing on?

Comment: Please include the imports with the MCVE.  In general if you cannot cut-and-paste into a text editor and run it to reproduce the result, you do not have a MCVE.

Do you have a link to that particular font?

Comment: @SteveCohen that font isn't free. It's probably possible to reproduce the problem with a free font, but that's the OPs problem, not ours.

Comment: Do you still have the problem if you use a generic serif font, rather than one that very few people here will have the inclination to download and install on their system? Plz make it easier for us to help u!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the font itself. It is anti-aliased fine on Mac, using Qt 4.8 64-bit, but Windows font renderer seems to be not advanced enough to antialias a font with PostScript outlines / OpenType layout. I tried to play with FontForge but couldn't make it anti-aliaseable on Windows so far.